# unable to import Metric from tensorflow.keras.metrics

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to write a custom metric evaluator for which I am following [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/training_and_evaluation#specifying_a_loss_metrics_and_an_optimizer). my dummy code is

```
import tensorflow as tf    
from tensorflow import keras    

class DummyMetric(keras.metrics.Metric):

    def __init__(self, name='categorical_true_positives', **kwargs):
      super(DummyMetric, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
      self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name='tp', initializer='zeros')

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
      print("Evaluating tensor of shape {} against gt of shape {}".format(y_pred.shape, y_true.shape))
      self.true_positives.assign_add(1.0)

    def result(self):
      return self.true_positives

    def reset_states(self):
      # The state of the metric will be reset at the start of each epoch.
      self.true_positives.assign(0.)
```

**my tensorflow version is 1.13.1 installed from source**.

`keras.metrics.Metric` throws

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.keras.metrics' has no attribute 'Metric'.

When I do `pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.14` then this error goes away.

please suggest any solution/hack if possible which will make it work without upgrading to 1.14

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like this was probably left out of an `__init__.py` and they fixed that in 1.14 I guess. I was able to import it this way:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.metrics import Metric
```

It is defined in file:

```
tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py
```