# keras.metrics has no attribute 'Metric'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I try to use Keras Tuner for hyperparameter optimisation:

```
import keras
from kerastuner import HyperModel
from kerastuner.tuners import Hyperband

input_shape = (1, 28, 28)
num_classes = 10

# Define hypermodel class
class CNNHyperModel(HyperModel):
    def __init__(self, input_shape, num_classes):
        self.input_shape = input_shape
        self.num_classes = num_classes

    def build(self, hp):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=input_shape))
        model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"))

        model.compile(
            loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
            optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
            metrics=["accuracy"],
        )

        return model

# Instantiate
hypermodel = CNNHyperModel(input_shape=input_shape, num_classes=num_classes)

# Create tuner
HYPERBAND_MAX_EPOCHS = 40
MAX_TRIALS = 20
EXECUTION_PER_TRIAL = 2
SEED = 1

tuner = RandomSearch(
    hypermodel,
    max_epochs=HYPERBAND_MAX_EPOCHS,
    objective='val_accuracy',
    seed=SEED,
    max_trials=MAX_TRIALS,
    executions_per_trial=EXECUTION_PER_TRIAL,
    directory='hyperband',
    project_name='mnist'
)
```

I get

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.keras.metrics' has no attribute 'Metric'

with both Tensorflow 1.13 and 2.0 installed using conda.

Including `from tensorflow.python.keras.metrics import Metric` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56688744/unable-to-import-metric-from-tensorflow-keras-metrics) does not change anything.

Comment: Do this `from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Metric`

Comment: That yields `ImportError: cannot import name 'Metric' from 'tensorflow.keras.metrics' (/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v1/keras/metrics/__init__.py)` unfortunately.

Comment: So you're using v1 I suppose

Comment: Please can you update TF to 1.15.2 and try. I am not facing any issues in TF 1.15.2  and TF 2.2.0-rc2  using```from tensorflow.python.keras.metrics import Metric```.

Comment: I noticed that I am indeed using TF 1.13. Although I have TF 2.0 installed in my virtual environment, when I print tf.__version__ it says 1.13. I'm coding in a jupyter in vscode and can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of Tensorflow 2.6.0 has [tf.keras.metrics.Metric](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Metric?version=nightly) API.

You can import as

```
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Metric
```